# How to resolve backend conn errors on haproxy load balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, https, haproxy

[haproxy stats page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMgGU.png)

The following is my haproxy config

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0 notice
    log /dev/log    local0 debug
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 5000
defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    option  tcpka
    timeout connect 60s
    timeout client 1000s
    timeout server 1000s

frontend aviator-app
    option tcplog
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    bind *:4433 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/{domain_name}.pem
    mode tcp
    option clitcpka
    option http-server-close
    maxconn 5000
    default_backend aviator-app-pool
    # Table definition
    stick-table type ip size 2000k expire 30s store conn_cur
    # Allow clean known IPs to bypass the filter
    tcp-request connection accept if { src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst }
    # Shut the new connection as long as the client has already 100 opened
    # tcp-request connection reject if { src_conn_cur ge 500 }
    tcp-request connection track-sc1 src

backend aviator-app-pool
    option tcplog
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    option srvtcpka
    option http-server-close
    maxconn 50
    # list each server
            server appserver1 10.0.1.205 maxconn 12
            server appserver2 10.0.1.183 maxconn 12
            server appserver3 10.0.1.75 maxconn 12
            server appserver4 10.0.1.22 maxconn 12
            # end of list

listen  stats
    bind            *:8000
    mode            http
    log             global

    maxconn 10

    clitimeout      100s
    srvtimeout      100s
    contimeout      100s
    timeout queue   100s

    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats refresh 30s
    stats show-node
    stats auth username:password
    stats uri  /haproxy?stats
```

When I run a load test with about 12-13 http requests per second, I do not see any errors for about first hour of the test. But about 90 mins into the test a large number of requests start failing. The error message from jmeter usually reads "Connection timed out: Connect" or '"domain_name:4433" failed to respond.'
The following are some log messages from haproxy.log. I also see a large number of 'conn errors' as highlighted in the image above and some 'resp errors'.

```
May  7 19:15:00 ip-10-0-0-206 haproxy[30349]: 64.112.179.79:55894 
[07/May/2018:19:14:00.488] aviator-app~ aviator-app-pool/<NOSRV> 
60123/-1/60122 0 sQ 719/718/717/0/0 0/672
May  7 19:15:00 ip-10-0-0-206 haproxy[30349]: 64.112.179.79:49905 
[07/May/2018:19:12:53.483] aviator-app~ aviator-app-pool/appserver2 
60022/1/127171 2283568 -- 719/718/716/11/0 0/666
```

I do not see any errors or stack trace on my backend servers. The CPU usage on load balancer is low during the test (less than 10%) for load balancer and about 30 % for each backend server. Any help to debug this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backend has `maxconn 50` so HAProxy is enqueueing the overflow waiting for one of the existing 50 to finish. When each connection disconnects, another one is allowed through to the back-end... but your back-end is not fast enough.   The requests are backing up at the proxy, and eventually, the proxy tears them down after they sit in the proxy queue for `timeout connect 60s`.

The `sQ` in the log entry is what explains this.

> `s`: the server-side timeout expired while waiting for the server to send or receive data.
>
> `Q`: the proxy was waiting in the QUEUE for a connection slot. This can only happen when servers have a 'maxconn' parameter set.

See [Session State at Disconnection](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.5) in the HAProxy configuration guide.

Comment: What would be the best way to resolve the issue ?
Should I increase the backend maxconn limit or increase the timeout or add more backend server instances ?
From the monitoring console, the CPU usage of individual backend servers does not exceed 30% and the memory usage is also not too high, so I would prefer not to add more instances unless it is the only way.

Comment: It really depends on why (or whether) your server can't handle more traffic than this.  Why are using `mode tcp` for what looks like it might be HTTPS traffic? (I'm guessing.)  Why is `maxconn 50`?

Comment: Yes, most of our requests are https. However, we are restricted to using tcp mode because of some malformed http request on the device firmware which cannot be changed easily. Do you think switching it to http mode will improve performance ?

Comment: Usually, `mode http` is a much better option, because back-end connections can be either reused or released quickly while waiting on the client's next request.  [`option accept-invalid-http-request`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-option%20accept-invalid-http-request) might relax the parser enough that  broken clients can still be supported... it depends on the nature of the error.